# SASS / Compass transition-property mixin not working with transform, and custom version not outputting prefixes

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to target the 'transform' property for a CSS3 transition with SASS and Compass. Here's what I want as output:

```
.panel { 
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
 }
```

First I tried the standard Compass mixin with

```
@import "compass/css3/transition";
@include transition(transform 0.5s ease-in-out);
```

However, all this outputs in the CSS is

```
transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
```

...which doesn't work in browsers yet, as it requires a prefix. There is a [bug report](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/289) from March 2011 referencing this, and it has supposedly been fixed. But, er, apparently not. So, I decided to roll my own to tide me over until I could work out how to submit a bug report.

This is what I put together:

```
@mixin transform-transition-mixin($duration, $easing) {

    -webkit-transition: transform $duration $easing;
    -moz-transition: transform $duration $easing;
    -o-transition: transform $duration $easing;
    transition: transform $duration $easing;

}
```

However this **still** only outputs

```
transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
```

Curiously, I decided to remove the last line, and it started working- but without the default value. Instead, this is what I get:

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
```

Can someone tell me what is going on, and the best way to fix it without just hard-coding everything?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of compass are you using? I just tried out the compass mixin on codepen and I got the output that you are expecting: http://codepen.io/sdsanders/pen/hLifb

Comment: @sdsanders 'compass version' is saying 0.12.6

Comment: Are you disabling browser prefixes anywhere? Maybe try explicitly turning them on? http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/exclude_vendor_prefixes/

Comment: @sdsanders I'll have to check on Monday, but if they're disabled it's not something that's been done by me. To the best of my knowledge I'm using the Sass / Compass defaults. It's running on top of Yeoman with the Angular generator. If it's something in the settings there, then 'Allo 'Allo indeed.

Comment: @sdsanders just had a look on the checked in version and explicitly set those variables at the top of the file- still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem with Sass or Compass, it's a problem with  a setting in Yeoman (or possibly just the Angular generator) and / or Autoprefixer. Deep in the Gruntfile is the autoprefixer task

```
autoprefixer: {
        options: {
            browsers: ['last 1 version']
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/'
            }]
        }
    },
```

I updated Autoprefixer by running

```
> npm update autoprefixer
```

at the terminal, and then changed the options to

```
options: {
            browsers: ['last 5 versions']
        },
```

...and now it works fine.